# Error: subprocess-exited-with-error when pip install mysqlclient

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install MySQLClinet on Ubuntu and when I `pip install mysqlclient` I get this error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8kpxdgiv/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8kpxdgiv/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-8kpxdgiv/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 155, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 49, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 28, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried, and it hasn't helped:

1. `pip install --upgrade setuptools`
2. `pip install ez_setup`
3. `sudo apt install mysql-server` - Do I actually need it?
4. `sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config`

Also I tried:
5. `pip install mysql-python` and it has this error:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-77bsfwx4/mysql-python_29535e9daccf4d7faed69e2300c5ded7/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          from setup_posix import get_config
        File "/tmp/pip-install-77bsfwx4/mysql-python_29535e9daccf4d7faed69e2300c5ded7/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
          from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Please notice I install it without virtual environment, is it okay?
I am trying to deploy my website to AWS EC2.
I am looking forward to your tips. Thanks in advance.

Finally I've added:
`sudo apt install libffi-dev` and it looks like it has helped. Hope it will help anybody else who meets the same problem on EC2.

Comment: Please post a solution _as answer below_ and self-accept it, to signal to others that a solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

So, to install MySQLClient on Ubuntu EC2 server you need:

The 1st:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config
```

And the 2nd:

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```

Then you can successfully:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

This has worked for me already 2 times on 2 EC2 Instances.